# using of freemarker template error occurs configuration failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, freemarker

```
@Autowired
private Configuration freemarkerConfig;
```

Getting the following exception,

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'freemarkerConfig';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'freeMarkerConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/freemarker/FreeMarkerServletWebConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'freeMarkerConfiguration' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'freeMarkerConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/freemarker/FreeMarkerServletWebConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is freemarker.core.Configurable$UnknownSettingException: Unknown FreeMarker configuration setting: "recognize_standard_file_extensions"
```

Comment: this might help: https://onecompiler.com/questions/3sse5cz2w/how-to-disable-freemarker-templates-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, make sure you are autowiring correct `FreeMarker Configuration`, or use

```
@Autowired
private freemarker.template.Configuration freeMarker;
```

Comment: sorry your solution doesn't work for me i found alternative solution @Bean
 public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer(){
  FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
  freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/templates"); //defines the classpath location of the freemarker templates
  freeMarkerConfigurer.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8"); // Default encoding of the template files
  return freeMarkerConfigurer;
 }